# PHP header Location: does not work on IE

Tags: php, header

```
header("Location: index.php");

header("Location: /");

header("Location: /",True,301);
```

....

Nothing work on IE, why & how can I fix this?

Comment: try to pass full url like `http://example.com` and place ` exit();` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `exit;` after `header('location:url');`.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
ob_start();
header("Location: https://sitename.com/login.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the complete `URL` in `header`.

```
header("Location: https://yoursite.com/index.php");
```